# Any guaranteed minimum sizes for types in C?

Tags: c, types, cross-platform

Can you generally make any assumptions about the minimum size of a data type?

What I have read so far:

- char:  1 Byte
- short: 2 Byte
- int:   2 Byte, typically 4 Byte
- long:  4 Byte

float??? double???

Are the values in `float.h` and `limits.h` system dependent?

Answer (score 36):

This is covered in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=C_data_types&oldid=376652910#Size):

> A `short int` must not be larger than an `int`.
> An `int` must not be larger than a `long int`.
>
> A `short int` must be at least 16 bits long.
> An `int` must be at least 16 bits long.
> A `long int` must be at least 32 bits long.
> A `long long int` must be at least 64 bits long.
>
> The standard does not require that any of these sizes be necessarily different. It is perfectly valid, for example, if all four types are 64 bits long.

Comment: There's a common misconception that char = byte = 8-bits. As stated in this answer, a char could very well be some other size (like 64-bits). sizeof just measures "how many chars would fit" in a given datatype. (so sizeof(char) == 1 by definition)

Comment: @Laurence: `char` isn't discussed in this answer at all?

Comment: @Jed: it's true that I didn't mention it, but it's a good piece of information to include in the answer (maybe it would have better fit as a comment to the question, though).

Comment: `char` is defined as at least 8 bits (`<limits.h> CHAR_BIT` is required to be at least 8).

Comment: Moreover, both POSIX and Windows require `CHAR_BIT` to be 8, so that means `CHAR_BIT` essentially **is 8** on ordinary desktop/workstation/server environments. The only exceptions are ancient legacy mainframes, DSPs, and possibly some embedded systems.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the values in `float.h` and `limits.h` are system dependent.  You should never make assumptions about the width of a type, but the standard does lay down some minimums. See §6.2.5 and §5.2.4.2.1 in the [C99 standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

For example, the standard only says that a `char` should be large enough to hold every character in the execution character set. It doesn't say how wide it is.

For the floating-point case, the standard hints at the order in which the widths of the types are given:

#### §6.2.5.10

> There are three *real ﬂoating types*, designated as **float**, **double**, and **long
>   double**. <sup>32)</sup> The set of values of the type **float** is a subset of the set of values of the type **double**; the set of values of the type **double** is a subset of the set of values of the type **long double**.

They implicitly defined which is wider than the other, but not specifically how wide they are. "Subset" itself is vague, because a `long double` can have the exact same range of a `double` and satisfy this clause.

This is pretty typical of how C goes, and a lot is left to each individual environment. You can't assume, you have to ask the compiler.

Comment: A char is required to be one byte. But a byte is not required to be 8 bits.

Comment: What about Annex F? In F.2.1 it appears to state that float matches the IEC 60559 single format and double matches the IEC 60559 double format. Sadly, I don't have 60559 available for reference but (the non-authoritative) Wikipedia seems to state that 60559 single is 32 and 60559 double is 64. Am I misreading something?

Comment: @altendky Adherence to Annex F is optional.

Answer (score 10):

Nine years and still no direct answer about the **minimum** size for `float, double, long double`.

---

> Any guaranteed minimum sizes for types in C?

For *floating point* type ...

From a *practical* point-of-view, `float` minimum size is **32-bits** and `double` is **64- bits**.  C allows `double` and `long double` to share similar characteristics, so a `long double` could be as small as a `double`: [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double#Implementations)<sup>1</sup> or 80-bit or 128-bit or ...

I could imagine a C compliant 48-bit `double` may have existed – yet do not know of any.

---

Now, let us imagine our rich uncle dies and left us a fortune to pay for the development and cultural promotion for **www.smallest_C_float.com**.

C specifies:

1. `float` finite range is at least [1E-37… 1E+37].  See `FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX`
2. `(1.0f + FLT_EPSILON) – 1.0f <= 1E-5`.
3. `float` supports positive and negative values.

   Let X: Digit 1-9
   Let Y: Digit 0-9
   Let E: value -37 to 36
   Let S: + or -
   Let b: 0 or 1

Our `float` could minimally represent all the combinations, using base 10, of `SX.YYYYY*10^E`.

`0.0` and `±1E+37` are also needed (3 more).  We do not need -0.0, sub-normals, ±infinity nor not-a-numbers.

That is 2*9*10<sup>5</sup>*74 + 3 combinations or 133,200,003 which needs at least 27 bits to encode - *somehow*.  Recall the goal is minimal size.

With a classic base 2 approach, we can assume an implied 1 and get
S1.bbbb_bbbb_bbbb_bbbb_b*2<sup>e</sup> or 2*2<sup>17</sup>*226 combinations or 26 bits.

If we try base 16, we then need about 2*15*16<sup>(4 or 5)</sup>*57 combinations or at least 26 to 30 bits.

Conclusion: A C `float` needs at least 26 bits of encoding.

---

A C’s `double` need not express a greater exponential range than `float`, it only has a different minimal precision requirement. `1E-9`.

S1.bbbb_bbbb_bbbb_bbbb_ bbbb_ bbbb_ bbbb_bb*2<sup>e</sup> --> 2*2<sup>30</sup>*226 combinations or 39 bits.

---

On our *imagine-if-you-will* computer, we could have a 13-bit `char` and so encode `float, double, long double` without padding.  Thus we can realize a non-padded 26-bit `float` and 39-bit `double, long double`.

---

<sup>1</sup>: [Microsoft Visual C++ for x86, which makes `long double` a synonym for `double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double#Implementations)

---

[Edit] 2020

Additional `double` requirements may require 41 bits.  May have to use 42-bit `double` and 28-bit `float`.  Will need to review.  Uncle will not be happy.

Answer (score 6):

However, the new C99 specifies (in `stdint.h`) optional types of minimal sizes, like `uint_least8_t`, `int_least32_t`, and so on..
(see [en_wikipedia_Stdint_h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h))

Comment: If your implementation doesn't have cstdint, try boost's cstdint which places the correct types in the boost namespace. I believe it delegates to the implementations cstdint if it has one.

Comment: @kts, Boost is a C++ library, the question is tagged C.

Comment: In the case of boost.cstdint it is both. Cstdint is almst entirely typedefs

Answer (score 4):

If you wan't to **check** the size (in multiples of chars) of any type on your system/platform really is the size you expect, you could do:

```
enum CHECK_FLOAT_IS_4_CHARS
{
   IF_THIS_FAILS_FLOAT_IS_NOT_4_CHARS = 1/(sizeof(float) == 4)
};
```

Comment: Huh?! Normally an assert is used. E.g. assert(sizeof(float) == 4);

Comment: 'assert' is a runtime function, hence to evaluate the statement the program needs to run. The above statement causes an error at compile-time if sizeof(float) is not 4.

Comment: struct { char check_float_is_4_chars[2*(sizeof(float)==4)-1]; };

Comment: #define STATIC_ASSERT(pred) switch(0){case 0:case pred:;}

Comment: Since C11, `static_assert ( sizeof(float)*CHAR_BIT == 32 , "(float) size != 32")`;

Answer (score 3):

Often developers asking this kind of question are dealing with arranging a packed `struct` to match a defined memory layout (as for a message protocol).  The assumption is that the language should directly specify laying out 16-, 24-, 32-bit, etc. fields for the purpose.

That is routine and acceptable for assembly languages and other application-specific languages closely tied to a particular CPU architecture, but is sometimes a problem in a general purpose language which might be targeted at who-knows-what kind of architecture.

In fact, the C language was not intended for a particular hardware implementation.  It was specified generally so a C compiler implementer could properly adapt to the realities of a particular CPU.  A Frankenstein hardware architecture consisting of 9 bit bytes, 54 bit words, and 72 bit memory addresses is easily—and unambiguously—mapped to C features.  (`char` is 9 bits; `short int`, `int`, and `long int` are 54 bits.)

This generality is why the C specification says something to the effect of "don't expect much about the sizes of ints beyond sizeof (char) <= sizeof (short int) <= sizeof (int) <= sizeof (long int)."  That implies that chars could be the same size as longs!

The current reality is—and the future seems to hold—that software demands architectures provide 8-bit bytes and that memory words addressable as individual bytes.  This wasn't always so.  Not too long ago, I worked on an the CDC Cyber architecture which features 6 bit "bytes" and 60 bit words.  A C implementation on that would be interesting.  In fact, that architecture is responsible for the weird packing semantics of Pascal—if anyone remembers that.

Comment: It is common on modern DSP architectures for the smallest addressable unit to be larger than 8bits, eg 32 bits.

Comment: I haven't run into any of those. Most DSPs I've programmed have bit addressed memory. That is for char *p, the expression (int)&p[1] - (int)p is eight.

Comment: The desire to be able to specify structure formats absolutely is reasonable; languages which are intended to allow code to be efficient and portable should include such a feature.  Since octets and groups of 2, 4, and 8 in big-endian and little-endian formats totally dominate everything else *for information interchange purposes*, I see no reason a compiler for *any* platform shouldn't be able to support signed and unsigned fixed-format values with a specified size and endianness.  Code using such types would perform poorly on systems where char isn't 8 bits, but if such types...

Comment: ...are used primarily for structures that are going to be processed as sequences of octets, performance need not be any worse than the code that would be necessary to work around their absence.

Answer (score 2):

**C99 N1256 standard draft**

http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf

C99 specifies two types of integer guarantees:

- minimum size guarantees
- relative sizes between the types

**Relative guarantees**

*6.2.5 Types*:

> 8 For any two integer types with the same signedness and different integer conversion rank
> (see 6.3.1.1), the range of values of the type with smaller integer conversion rank is a
> subrange of the values of the other type.

and *6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers* determines the relative conversion ranks:

> 1 Every integer type has an integer conversion rank defined as follows:
>
> - The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which
>   shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short
>   int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.
> - The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
>   signed integer type, if any.
> - For all integer types T1, T2, and T3, if T1 has greater rank than T2 and T2 has
>   greater rank than T3, then T1 has greater rank than T3

**Absolute minimum sizes**

Mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/a/1738587/895245 , here is the quote for convenience.

*5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`*:

> 1 [...] Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown [...]
>
> - UCHAR_MAX 255 // 2 8 − 1
> - USHRT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
> - UINT_MAX 65535 // 2 16 − 1
> - ULONG_MAX 4294967295 // 2 32 − 1
> - ULLONG_MAX 18446744073709551615 // 2 64 − 1

**Floating point**

If the `__STDC_IEC_559__` macro is defined, then IEEE types are guaranteed for each C type, although `long double` has a few possibilities: [Is it safe to assume floating point is represented using IEEE754 floats in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967040/is-it-safe-to-assume-floating-point-is-represented-using-ieee754-floats-in-c/31967139#31967139)

Comment: @chux the Two Out Of Three made me smile. Are you referring to `float` and `double` vs `long double`? I think it is well explained enough on the link.

Comment: Yes, there are narrow guarantees in 2 of 3 types: `float` and `double`,

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the standard does give what is defined to be "the correct answer" but it doesn't actually reflect the way programs are generally written.

People make assumptions all the time that char is 8 bits, short is 16, int is 32, long is either 32 or 64, and long long is 64.

Those assumptions are not a great idea but you will not get fired for making them.

In theory, `<stdint.h>` can be used to specify fixed-bit-width types, but you have to scrounge one up for Microsoft. ([See here for a MS stdint.h](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h).) One of the problems here is that C++ technically only needs C89 compatibility to be a conforming implementation; even for plain C, C99 is not fully supported even in 2009.

It's also not accurate to say there is no width specification for `char`. There is, the standard just avoids saying whether it is signed or not. Here is what C99 actually says:

- number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
  `CHAR_BIT 8`
- minimum value for an object of type signed char
  `SCHAR_MIN -127` // -(2<sup>7</sup> - 1)
- maximum value for an object of type signed char
  `SCHAR_MAX +127` // 2<sup>7</sup> - 1
- maximum value for an object of type unsigned char
  `UCHAR_MAX 255` // 2<sup>8</sup> - 1

Comment: Those are minimum requirements. There's nothing in the Standard that forbids an implementation to define CHAR_BIT as `9`, or `16`, `18`, ...

Comment: "int is 32"  ---> Hmmm.  Often in embedded C, `int` is 16-bit - as allowed by the C spec.  100 of millions per year in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the libraries define something like this:

```
#ifdef MY_ARCHITECTURE_1
typedef unsigned char u_int8_t;
typedef short int16_t;
typedef unsigned short u_int16_t;
typedef int int32_t;
typedef unsigned int u_int32_t;
typedef unsigned char u_char;
typedef unsigned int u_int;
typedef unsigned long u_long;
typedef unsigned short u_short;
#endif
```

you can then use those typedef in your programs instead of the standard types.