# is there a "double" type in PHP

Tags: php

if not, then how to declare a double type of number?

```
function testFloat(float $f)
{
    return $f;
}

echo testFloat(1.2);
```

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to testFloat() must be an instance of float, double given

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

Regarding [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php):

> Type Hints can only be of the **object** and **array** (since PHP 5.1) type. Traditional type hinting with int and string isn't supported.

So I don't know, but probably you get the error because only `array` and `object` types are supported.

---

I am not exactly sure what you want, but there is only [**`float`**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php):

> Floating point numbers (also known as "floats", "doubles", or "real numbers") can be specified using any of the following syntaxes:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $a = 1.234; 
> $b = 1.2e3; 
> $c = 7E-10;
> ?>
> ```

and there you find also:

> **Converting to float**
>
> For information on converting strings
>   to float , see [String conversion to  numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion). For values of other types,
>   the conversion is performed by
>   converting the value to integer first
>   and then to float . See [Converting to integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) for more information. As of
>   PHP 5, a notice is thrown if an object
>   is converted to float .

Comment: what he meant is precision: there are single and double precision (4 and 8 bytes usually) floating point numbers.

Answer (score 5):

The `float` type in PHP is implemented internally as a C `double`. The size of such type is unspecified by the C standard, which only requires that `sizeof(float) <= sizeof(double) <= sizeof(long double)`.

#### §6.2.5.10

> There are three *real floating types*, designated as **float**, **double**, and **long double**.<sup>34)</sup> The set of values of the type **float** is a subset of the set of values of the type **double**; the set of values of the type **double** is a subset of the set of values of the type **long double**.

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738568/any-guaranteed-minimum-sizes-for-types-in-c/1738587#1738587))

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 2):

The error has nothing to do with float or double. Since type hinting only works with array or object, PHP thinks "float" is a class. Don't use type-hinting for primitive scalar types. PHP is an untyped language. It doesn't make sense to do that.

To further drive my point, you can try this example,

```
function testFloat(integer $f)
{
    return $f;
}

echo testFloat(1);
```

You get the similar error,

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to testFloat() must be an instance of integer, integer given, called in /private/tmp/test.php on line 8 and defined in /private/tmp/test.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php
And, please, read See Also.