# How to pass double value from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html, ebay-api

I want to pass a **`Double`** value (`i.e. 10.9`) from an HTML file to PHP. Here is my HTML code:

```
        <form action="AddProduct.php" method="POST" target="_self">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <label class="lbl"> Title: </label> &nbsp
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" maxlength="100" size=20>
                    <label class="lbl"> Price: </label> &nbsp &nbsp
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price" maxlength=100>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <label class="lbl"> Description: </label> &nbsp <br>
                    <textarea rows="10" cols="37" name="description"></textarea>
                </tr>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <input class="btn" type="Submit" name="save" value="Save">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$config = require __DIR__.'/../configuration.php';

use \DTS\eBaySDK\Constants;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Services;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types;
use \DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Enums;

$siteId = Constants\SiteIds::US;

$service = new Services\TradingService(array(
    'apiVersion' => $config['tradingApiVersion'],
    'sandbox' => true,
    'siteId' => $siteId,
    'authToken' => $config['sandbox']['userToken'],
    'devId' => $config['sandbox']['devId'],
    'appId' => $config['sandbox']['appId'],
    'certId' => $config['sandbox']['certId'],
));

$request = new Types\AddFixedPriceItemRequestType();

$request->RequesterCredentials = new Types\CustomSecurityHeaderType();
$request->RequesterCredentials->eBayAuthToken = $config['sandbox']['userToken'];

$item = new Types\ItemType();

$item->Title = urlencode($_POST['title']);
$item->Description = urlencode($_POST['description']);

$item->StartPrice = new Types\AmountType(array('value' => urlencode($_POST['price'])));

$request->Item = $item;

$response = $service->addFixedPriceItem($request);

if (isset($response->Errors)) {
    foreach ($response->Errors as $error) {
        printf("%s: %s\n%s\n\n",
            $error->SeverityCode === Enums\SeverityCodeType::C_ERROR ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
        $error->ShortMessage,
        $error->LongMessage
        );
    }
}

if ($response->Ack !== 'Failure') {
    printf("The item was listed to the eBay Sandbox with the Item number %s\n",
        $response->ItemID
    );
}
```

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'DTS\eBaySDK\Exceptions\InvalidPropertyTypeException' with message
>   'Invalid property type: DTS\eBaySDK\Trading\Types\AmountType::value
>   expected , got ' in
>   /var/www/html/gitsamp/ebay-sdk-examples/vendor/dts/ebay-sdk/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Types/BaseType.php:433
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/gitsamp/ebay-sdk-examples/vendor/dts/ebay-sdk/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Types/BaseType.php(263): DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType::ensurePropertyType('DTS\eBaySDK\Typ...',
>   'value', '16.99') #1
>   /var/www/html/gitsamp/ebay-sdk-examples/vendor/dts/ebay-sdk/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Types/BaseType.php(231): DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType->set('DTS\eBaySDK\Typ...', 'value',
>   '16.99') #2
>   /var/www/html/gitsamp/ebay-sdk-examples/vendor/dts/ebay-sdk/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Types/DoubleType.php(51):
>   DTS\eBaySDK\Types\BaseType->setValues('DTS\eBaySDK\Typ...', Array) #3
>   /var/www/html/gitsamp/ebay-sdk-examples/vendor/dts/ebay-sdk-trading/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Trading/Types/AmountType.php(49):
>   DTS\eBaySDK\Types\DoubleType->__construct(Array) #4 /var/www/h in
>   /var/www/html/gitsamp/ebay-sdk-examples/vendor/dts/ebay-sdk/src/DTS/eBaySDK/Types/BaseType.php
>   on line 433

Comment: You need to get price as double ?

Comment: `urlencode()` expects a string, not a numeric value as input. Maybe the error occurs somewhere else?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194932/is-there-a-double-type-in-php will help you about double type

Comment: yes @KTAnj . I want to pass a double value from HTML to PHP.

Comment: `$price= (double) $_POST['price'];` Did you try this ?

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Answer:**
The value you're dealing with in `$price` is a string, change it to a double in the PHP code with `floatval()`:

```
$price = '';
$price = urlencode($_POST['price']);
$price_float_value = floatval($price);
echo $price_float_value;
```

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Also, side note: floating point numbers are dangerous with money transactions. You may want to use integers and break the values into dollars and cents to avoid losing accuracy.

**HTML Answer:**
If you're not for PHP code translation, then you can set the accuracy in HTML with:

```
<input type="number" step="0.01">
```

step will allow the given accuracy of a number.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `floatval()`

```
$price = '';
$price = urlencode($_POST['price']);
$price_float_value = floatval($price);
echo $price_float_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data you are trying to POST to the PHP script will be posted as a string, regardless of what the data type is on the HTML page. If you want to validate the data, you can use a PHP function to determine whether the data is int, double, etc.

To check if the value is a double you could use,

```
if ($price == (string) (float) $price) {

    // $price is a float/double

    $price = (float) $price; // converts the var to float

}
```