# range of primitive datatypes in C?

Tags: c, primitive-types

I am learning C language and got the following range of primitive data types:

[image]

I dont know where the values in the **Range** column come from.

Comment: It comes from ... the number of bytes listed in the Length column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any guaranteed minimum sizes for types in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738568/any-guaranteed-minimum-sizes-for-types-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `int` is 16-bit, it means there are `2^16` different values. Of these, `2^15 (= 32,768)` (half) are negative, `2^15 - 1 (= 32,767)` are positive and the last one is `0`.

The same reasoning can be used for 8-bit, 32-bit or any other size of integer.

For floating point numbers (float and double), the how the range is [explained on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point_number#Range_of_floating-point_numbers) or on Steve Hollasch's page on [IEEE Standard 754 Floating Point Numbers](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).

Comment: why has to -1 for positive? (2^15 - 1)

Comment: `0` takes up one spot, so both can't be `2^15`. You can think of it as `2^15` negative integers and `2^15` non-negative integers (i.e. including `0`), which makes for a total of `2^16` integers.