# Are there float and double types with fixed sizes in C99?

Tags: c, floating-point, c99

C99 states integer types like uint32_t, int16_t etc, where it's easy to see the number of bits used. Good to know in for instance embedded programming.

I have not found any similar types for floating point values. Is there a standard? If not, why?

Comment: There aren't any similar sized type names for `float`, `double`, `long double`.  If the decimal floating point arithmetic of IEEE 754:2008 becomes widespread (currently mainly found in IBM chips, notably the Power chips), then you'll see some names with sizes (see: [TR 24732](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#24732)) such as `_Decimal32`, `_Decimal64` and `_Decimal128` — however, not in C99 or C2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in  [Any guaranteed minimum sizes for types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738568/any-guaranteed-minimum-sizes-for-types-in-c)

Quoting Jed Smith (with corrected link to C99 standard):

Yes, the values in `float.h` and `limits.h` are system dependent.  You should never make assumptions about the width of a type, but the standard does lay down some minimums. See §6.2.5 and §5.2.4.2.1 in the [C99 standard](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf).

For example, the standard only says that a `char` should be large enough to hold every character in the execution character set. It doesn't say how wide it is.

For the floating-point case, the standard hints at the order in which the widths of the types are given:

#### §6.2.5.10

> There are three *real ﬂoating types*, designated as **float**, **double**, and **long
>   double**. <sup>32</sup>) The set of values of the type **float** is a subset of the set of values of the type **double**; the set of values of the type **double** is a subset of the set of values of the type **long double**.

They implicitly defined which is wider than the other, but not specifically how wide they are. "Subset" itself is vague, because a `long double` can have the exact same range of a `double` and satisfy this clause.

This is pretty typical of how C goes, and a lot is left to each individual environment. You can't assume, you have to ask the compiler.

Comment: Yes, but in an embedded system you don't want to ask the compiler, you want a specific size. Maybe because of storage limitations. 

I don't understand why C99 didn't just specify such names. Their internal representation does not necessary have to be the same, even if that of cause would have been great.

Comment: if you just need a "predefined size" why not define a union ?

Comment: In an embedded system you usually want to make certain that an array don't get too big. You want to have 200000 **32 bit** ints because your memory is only 1 MB, and therefore you write int32_t. In this case there is no room for 64 bit integers. I can then use a C99 type, but there is no equivalent float type.

I don't see how a union should serve any purpose in this case. Unions only make things bigger...

Comment: I proposed unions only to assure a datastructure of constant size, i.e. `union { int8_t dummy[8]; double value;}` ; whatever the length of a double (as long as it does not exceed 64bit), the union is 64bit long. But it will not solve portability issues (sizeof(double) 80bit on one plateform and 64bit on another)

Comment: What about Annex F?  In F.2.1 it appears to state that float matches the IEC 60559 single format and double matches the IEC 60559 double format.  Sadly, I don't have 60559 available for reference but (the non-authoritative) Wikipedia seems to state that 60559 single is 32 and 60559 double is 64.  Am I misreading something?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "why" part of your question, the name `uint32_t`, for example, tells you everything you need to know about the type: it's unsigned and exactly 32 bits wide, which implies a range of exactly `0` to `4294967295`.  (The C standard requires that the `uintN_t` types have no padding bits or trap representations, and that the signed `intN_t` types use two's-complement.)

On the other hand, specifying the size in bits of a floating-point type doesn't tell you nearly as much.  A hypothetical `float64_t` would be exactly 64 bits, but the bits that make up a floating-point object are divided into the sign bit, exponent, and significand (mantissa).  Furthermore, the meaning of those bits can vary.  In most representations, the exponent denotes a power of 2, but it can also be a power of 16.  And there are numerous special representations: subnormals, denormals, NaNs, infinities, negative zero.

There are more variations in floating-point representations than can easily be encoded in a type name.

The IEEE floating-point standard (more properly IEC 60559) defines all this -- but if your implementation supports IEC 60559, then the C standard specifies the meanings of `float` and `double` anyway (though it allows some more flexibility for `long double`).

Comment: Actually, uint32_t doesn't say everything one might want to know.  It doesn't indicate what other types, if any, it is alias-compatible with, nor what alignment it requires, nor how the bits are divided among the `sizeof (uint32_t)` characters comprising a type, nor whether the type will promote as signed or unsigned.  I don't think a compiler for any platform should have any particular difficulty supporting an integer type which which stored 8 bits in each of four characters in big-endian order, and another which did likewise in little-endian order, and in either case...

Comment: ...was alias-compatible with all other fixed-format types [on machines where char isn't 8 bits, the types would be defined as having charsize-8 padding bits within each char].  The existence of such types wouldn't "discriminate" against systems with 9-bit char but quite the opposite: it would make it possible for such systems to run without modification code that was primarily intended for 8-bit systems and used such types in cases where they needed to exchange octet-based data with other systems.

Answer (score 1):

While the vast majority of C compilers include a 32-bit integer type, there are many where the only 32-bit type is `int` and on others the only 32-bit types is `long`.  Having a standard name `int32_t` mean "one of the signed 32-bit type" avoids the need for the programmer to know *which* built-in type is 32 bits, except on compilers which use aggressive type-based aliasing.

By contrast, the vast majority of compilers that can use an IEEE single-precision value call it `float`, and those that can use an IEEE double-precision value call it `double`.  It would not be inconceivable that a compiler might use the names `float` and `double` to identify something other than IEEE types and yet include the IEEE types under some other name, but such a scenario would likely be too rare for the Standard to worry about.