# float and double on different platforms

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

Is the format and size of a float or double on all major development systems (windows, Linux and Mac) is the same?

Is there any way to make sure that they are compatible with each other? For example, I can make sure that an int is 32 bit by using int32_t as type instead of int, but is there any similar technique for float and double?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't:

1) format: depends on the *endianness* of your architecture.

2) size: `double` is mandated to be no smaller than a `float`. Anything else is permissible.

see the C standard:

§6.2.5.10

> There are three real ﬂoating types, designated as float, double, and
>   long double. The set of values of the type float is a subset of the
>   set of values of the type double; the set of values of the type double
>   is a subset of the set of values of the type long double.

See also [Any guaranteed minimum sizes for types in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738568/any-guaranteed-minimum-sizes-for-types-in-c)

Comment: There are also constraints involving the minimum ranges and precision.  And endianness doesn't affect the format; it only comes into play when you try to access a variable as an array of bytes (and there's practically never any reason to do that).

Comment: @James Kanze: that's a good clarification but I took format to *mean* the byte arrangement. Perhaps the OP meant the arrangment of mantissa / exponent, as I think you do.

Comment: It's actually quite possible that the OP meant byte arrangement.  In which case, it should be pointed out that this is _not_ really part of the format, since all of the machines I know today access `float` and `double` as "words", and not as a sequence of bytes.

Comment: The question states that `int32_t` is a solution for integers, so presumably endianness is already either understood or irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "major development systems".
Windows and most Unix systems use IEEE float and double, so they
will use the same format.  Most mainframes (including IBM) use
some other format.

The real question is why you need compatibility.  If you're
worried about portability, you *don't* use `int32_t`, because
there are still some platforms which don't support it.  More
generally, in all but exceptional cases, you should be using
`int`, and validating the input against expressions involving
`INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` to ensure that no overflow can occur.

Comment: Neither Windows nor Unix nor any other operating system determines the way data types are stored. These are aspects of the compiler (to determine width) and CPU (to determine layout), and sometimes both CPU and compiler (for architectures that support multiple layouts).

Comment: @mah: you can take a pure view that it's a feature of the implementation and therefore up to the compiler (which might be informed by the CPU). Alternatively you can take the practical view that a hosted C++ implementation will want to expose system APIs to the programmer, therefore will use the OS's ABI or close to it. As far as `extern "C"` linkage is concerned, anyway, and that includes the layout of basic types. The practical view is more useful for programmers, the pure view applies for example if you emulate one architecture on another.

Comment: @mah Sort of.  Windows only runs on Intel compatible, so it uses Intel representations.  Unix is more general, but the standard does make some restrictions as to architecture (most importantly that all pointers have the same size and representation), but the fact that there can be variants is why I said "most Unix systems".  (Some versions of Unix do run on IBM mainframes, and they do not use IEEE.  I suspect that most IBM mainframes run IBM OS's, rather than Unix, however.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Windows can be tightly paired to Intel however it's still an incorrect selection of identifier. For example, MacOS can be tightly paired to 68k I mean PowerPC I mean Intel (and lets ignore it's highly similar iOS Sister that runs on ARM). There are arguments to dismiss that example, so consider instead your statement about pointer size, x86 vs x86-64 and suddenly the same OS holds different sizes. I agree, your "most" qualifier is correct but I don't see reason to refer to the OS when architecture is so close at hand -- _and_ accurate to its needs explicitly.

Comment: @SteveJessop It seems a given that an implementation of C++ will respect the platform ABI for the common elements (which conceivably wouldn't include `float` or `double`).  It also seems given that it will use the "native" representation for types which are directly supported by hardware (which doesn't necessarily include `float` or `double`).  Beyond that, it's pretty much anything goes, and of course, the system ABI may be parametrized itself: Posix defines an ABI where the size and representation of the basic types is only slightly specified (`char` must be 8 bits, etc.).

Comment: @mah You might want to qualify the system with the platform architecture; it is certainly necessary in the case of Unix (Posix or Linux, which run on several different platforms).  In the case of Windows, no qualifier is needed.  (In this case, of course.  You would need to distinguish between Windows 32 and Windows 64 if we ask about `long long`.)

Comment: I think Windows 8 runs on ARM, too, and the XBox 360 ran a Windows-derived OS on PowerPC. Those are definitely mainstream platforms. But @mah, Windows on ARM is one of those funny systems where the OS defines the endianness, not the compiler nor the CPU.