# Why does my code produce more alloc'd memory than I asked for?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, hashtable, free

```
typedef struct hash_node_s
{
    char *key;
    char *value;
    struct hash_node_s *next;
} hash_node_t;

typedef struct hash_table_s
{
    unsigned long int size;
    hash_node_t **array;
} hash_table_t;

hash_table_t *hash_table_create(unsigned long int size)
{
    hash_table_t *table;

    table = malloc(sizeof(hash_table_t));

    if (!table)
    {
        printf("failed to create table");
        return (NULL);
    }

    table->size = size;
    table->array = malloc(sizeof(hash_node_t *) * size);

    if (!table->array)
    {
        printf("failed to create table->array");
        free(table);
        return (NULL);
    }

    return (table);
}

int main(void)
{
    hash_table_t *ht;

    ht = hash_table_create(1024);
    printf("%p\n", (void *)ht);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When I run using Valgrind, I expect 2 allocs, 0 frees, however:

```
root@anon# valgrind ./a
==1374== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1374== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1374== Using Valgrind-3.18.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1374== Command: ./a
==1374==
0x4a8c040
==1374==
==1374== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1374==     in use at exit: 8,208 bytes in 2 blocks
==1374==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 9,232 bytes allocated
==1374==
==1374== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1374==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==1374==    indirectly lost: 8,192 bytes in 1 blocks
==1374==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1374==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1374==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1374== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1374==
==1374== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1374== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Anyone have any idea where the extra alloc and free is coming from? I'm using Valgrind 3.18.1

I've tried running with --leak-check=full and various other options, but nothing is clarifying this, and ChatGPT is just a dumb program, so please don't recommend that thing, nor Phind.

Comment: It's hard to say with any confidence, but likely something in the standard library is allocating working space and then cleaning it up at exit.  My money would be on `printf`.

Comment: Perhaps your `printf` implementation does. Related: [Does printf() allocate memory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39861660/does-printf-allocate-memory-in-c)

Comment: Aside: *"please don't recommend [ChatGPT]"*. Such mention is [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: OT: `return` is not a function call. Those parentheses are not needed (and are actually distracting in that their presence suggests the return value is _special_.) Also, `table = malloc( sizeof *table );` is both clearer and _safer_ and less to maintain. Finally, `calloc()` of the table elements array would be nicer than more code in a DIY initialisation.

Comment: What is the output of `--leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes`? This should show where the memory of the leaks is allocated.

Answer (score 0):

The third allocation may have been performed by `printf` or during the C runtime initialization to allocate the buffer for the standard streams.

You can free those by closing the standard streams prior to leaving the `main` function with:

```
    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
```

Comment: so why, then does this get ignored by valgrind in some other versions?

Comment: It depends on whether Valgrind was properly parameterized to recognize the standard stream allocations or not.