# Is the minimum size of datatypes defined in bits or bytes?

Tags: c, types, byte, size, bit

I know that the number of bits in a `char` is defined in `CHAR_BIT` from `<limits.h>` and that `sizeof(char)` is always 1. But what about other basic datatypes, are their sizes defined relative to `CHAR_BIT`?

For example the minimum size of an `int` in C is defined as 16 bits [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Main_types), but on other sites like [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-types-in-c/) the minimum size is defined as 2 bytes. Which definition is correct as a byte is not necessarily the same as 8 bits.

Comment: Other datatypes are defined in integer multiples of `sizeof (char)`. Any structure, with bitfields and what not, will occupy `<some integer> * sizeof (char) * CHAR_BIT` bits... same as `<some integer> * sizeof (char)` *bytes* (bytes, not necessarily *octets*)

Comment: If `CHAR_BIT` was 16, the min size of `int` remains 16 bits - and in this case, 1 "byte".

Comment: Yes, `INT_MAX` is `32767` or larger... and `32767` needs 15+1 bits. So if `CHAR_BIT` is 8 ==> `sizeof (int) >= 2`; if `CHAR_BIT` is 16 ==> `sizeof (int) >= 1`

Comment: The sizes of other data types are not defined relative to `CHAR_BIT` in the C standard, if that's what you're asking. The minimum size of an `int` is 16 bits according to the standard, irrespective of `CHAR_BIT`

Comment: An `int` must represent values in *at least* the range `[-32767..32767]`, meaning an `int` must be *at least* 16 bits wide.  They may be wider (and are on most modern platforms).  Also, *at least* 16 bits doesn't mean *exactly* 16 bits - oddball platforms may have *padding bits* that don't contribute to the value representation.  It's possible to have a 9-bit platform that uses 18 bits to store an int, but two bits are padding bits and it still only stores the range `[-32767..32767]`.

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. I think this is a very good question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum required range of values of a type is defined numerically, not in terms of bits or bytes. [5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) says has definitions like:

> - minimum value for an object of type `short int`
>   `SHRT_MIN`                               -32767 // -(2<sup>15</sup> - 1)
> - maximum value for an object of type `short int`
>   `SHRT_MAX`                               +32767 // 2<sup>15</sup> - 1

All the type definitions happen to match up with implementing the types using either two's complement or sign-magnitude representation with a multiple of 8 bit bytes. But since they're just minimums, it doesn't require such representations.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the minimum size of datatypes defined in bits or bytes?

Mostly it is defined by a combination of C specification properties and `CHAR_BIT`.  `CHAR_BIT >= 8`.

`int` has a minimum range [-32767... 32767] obliging al least 16 bits to encode that.

With the common `CHAR_BIT == 8`, that is 16-bits or 2 byte".

With the common `CHAR_BIT == 16`, that is 16-bits or 1 "byte".  A *byte* being 16-bits in this implementation.

With the common `CHAR_BIT == 64`, that is 64-bits or 1 "byte".  64 bits, as no type is smaller than `char`.

---

Exact size integer types like `(u)intN_t` are effectively defined by bit size.  They too have min/max range values, but with the no padding and 2's complement requirement are effectively defined by *bits*.  Note: these are optional types.

---

Some esoteric thoughts about the minnum [floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883952/2410359) bit size.