# Does C uses 2's complement internally to evaluate unsigned numbers arithmetic like 5-4?

Tags: c, logic, unsigned, digital

I have C code as

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 5;
    unsigned int b = 4;
    printf("%u",a-b);
}
```

Output of above code is 1, I am thinking that C has calculated internally the result as taking 2's compliment of -4 and then using compliment arithmetic to evaluate the result. Please correct me if anything I am interpreting wrong. (Here, I am talking about how C actually calculates result using binary)

Comment: The internal representation is not not mandated by the C standard (it allows 3 different representations - 1&2-complement and sign-and-magnitude)

Comment: In essentially every practical C implementation, this arithmetic operation is performed by a single processor instruction that sends the values to an arithmetic unit that is a series of “logic gates” that have bits as inputs and outputs. At this level, the manipulations are below the meaning of two’s complement and are only loosely tied to binary representation. For addition and subtraction, ALUs use the same gates for unsigned binary as they do for two’s complement, because the individual bits work the same way.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: There is no negative result here, and 4 is not negated when `5-4` is evaluated. The operation is semantically a direct subtraction, not a negation and addition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh. Looks that I have misinterpreted the whole question

Comment: I am saying like when we subtract two unsigned numbers in 2's compliment arithmetic  by taking 2's compliment of subtrahend and then adding it to the minuend, we get the result but in C, the same happens or not , I have doubt in that!

Comment: @HarshitSingh This does not matter, it is hidden by the implementation (likely on hardware level) and does not affect the observed result.

Answer (score 3):

> Does C uses 2's complement internally to evaluate unsigned numbers arithmetic like 5-4?

No, for two reasons.

```
unsigned int a = 5, b = 4;
printf("%u",a-b);
```

C guarantees that arithmetic on `unsigned` integer types is performed modulo the size of the type.  So if you computed `b-a`, you'd get -1 which would wrap around to `UINT_MAX`, which is probably either 65535 or 4294967295 on your machine.  But if you compute `a-b`, that's just an ordinary subtraction that doesn't overflow or underflow in any way, so the result is an uncomplicated 1 without worrying about 2's complement or modulo arithmetic or anything.

If your compiler, or your CPU architecture, chooses to implement `a - b` as `a + -b`, that's their choice, but it's an implementation detail way beneath the visibility of the C Standard, or ordinary programmers like you and me, and it won't affect the observable results of a C program at all.

Where things get interesting, of course, is with addition and subtraction of *signed* quantities.  Up above I said that under unsigned arithmetic, 4 - 5 is -1 which wraps around to `UINT_MAX`.  Using signed arithmetic, of course, 4 - 5 is -1 which is -1.  Under 2's complement arithmetic, it Just So Happens that the bit patterns for -1 and `UINT_MAX` are identical (typically `0xffff` or `0xffffffff`), and this is why 2's complement arithmetic is popular, because your processor gets to define, and your C compiler gets to use, just one set of `add` and `sub` instructions, that work equally well for doing signed and unsigned arithmetic.  But (today, at least), C does *not* mandate 2's complement arithmetic, and that's the other reason why the answer to your original question is "no".

---

But to be clear (and to go back to your question): Just about any C compiler, for just about any architecture, is going to implement `a - b` by emitting some kind of a `sub` instruction.  Whether the processor then chooses to implement `sub` as a two's complement negate-and-add, or some other kind of negate-and-add, or via dedicated bitwise subtraction-with-borrow logic, is entirely up to that processor, and it doesn't matter (and is probably invisible) as long as it always returns a mathematically appropriate result.

Comment: 32767 for those of us still using 15-bit machines.

Comment: @Eljay 15-bit machines??  I've heard of 16-bit machines, but nary a 15-bit one.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica • I've not heard of a 15-bit one either, but when `UINT_MAX` is 32767 that'll be one.  (I did program on a 13-bit-per-byte virtual machine in college, of the professor's own creation.  I learned a lot from the class, such as "never take any more classes by that professor".)

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for the tip.  Sigh.  More and more cranial flatulence these days, if you catch my drift.

Comment: @Eljay Perhaps along the same lines as your professor, I've been thinking of creating a 5-bit micro-float type, to demonstrate and teach the internals of floating-point formats, but perhaps it's best I haven't completed that project. :-)

Comment: Steve, maybe a 13-bit char to facilitate the [smallest FP types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883952/2410359)?

Comment: @chux hahahaha.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic method generally whatever is most natural on the target hardware. It is not defined by the C language.

When a processor's ALU has at least `int` sized registers, `a-b` will not doubt be implemented as a single `SUB` instruction (or whatever the target's op-code mnemonic for subtraction might be).  In the hardware logic it may well be that the logic is equivalent to `a + (~b + 1)` (i.e. 2's complement the RHS and add) - but that is a hardware logic/micro-code implementation issue, not a language or compiler behaviour.

At [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/YGh1WWhG7) for GCC x86 64-bit, the statement:

```
 unsigned int c = a - b ;
```

generates the following assembly code (my comments):

```
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]      ; Load a to EAX
    sub     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]      ; Subtract b from EAX
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax     ; Write result to c
```

So in that sense your question is not valid - C does not do anything in particular, the processor performs the subtraction intrinsically.

The C standard *allows* 2's, 1's and sign+magnitude arithmetic, but in practice the world has settled on 2's complement and machines that use other representations are arcane antiques that probably never had C compilers targeted for them in any case.

There are in any case moves to remove the option for anything other than 2's complement in the language: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2218.htm