# Manipulating float bits using unions: Finding the correct uint type that fits the float

Tags: c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, union

In C, I’ve seen this code used as a way to manipulate a float, down to the bits:

```c
union {
    uint32_t bits;
    float value;
}
```

By defining a variable of this type, one can perform bitwise operations on the `var.bits` side, while `var.value` evaluates to the floating-point value itself which in turn can be printed and used in expressions.

However, the code relies on the fact that the `float` width matches the `unit32_t` size. While this is usually the case, I’m curious about how to implement this code without such an assumption, i.e. it chooses the correct fixed-width integer based on the float size.

An approach that comes to mind is to use a bunch of `if` statements and branch out by comparing `sizeof(float)` and `stdint.h` width constants, e.g.:

```c
if (sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t)) {
    // Define the union with float and uint32_t and do the manipulations ...  
} else if (sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint64_t)) {
    // Define the union with float and uint64_t and do the manipulations ...  
}
else ...
```

This would work but the codes would have to be repeated in each if statement. I prefer to declare and initialize the variable itself globally, right after the type declaration itself, something like this:

```c
union {
    uint32_t bits;
    float val;
} var = {UINTMAX_C(1)};
```

So the branch would need to happen statically at the preprocess level, and `sizeof`s don’t work in `#if`.

Is there another way to find the correct fixed-width integer type for the float?

Comment: People usually do this at configuration time by running a small C program that outputs the correct definition as a C code fragment.

Comment: @TomKarzes I apologize for the mistake in the typedefs. I didn’t notice that the new type would be usable only in that specific local scope. Editing the post now.

Comment: Pedantic: Theoretical machines may have `float` as small as [28 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883952/2410359).  Not all machines have `(u)intN_t` of 8,16,32,64 - although that is increasing rare these days.

Comment: In my opinion you only need to add static assertion for `sizeof(uint32_t) == sizeof(float)`. In very unlikely event that assertion fails, it will affect assumptions you made about performance and memory usage, but also about precision and accuracy. It means that you will have to review the code anyway. I makes no sense to spend time by trying to predict something that might never happen. If assertion fails, worry about it then when you have more information available.

Comment: It is sometimes helpful to alias the float onto more than one way of looking at it. One of the tricks for high precision cube root relies on zapping the low 32bits of a double mantissa to zero so that computing its square will  be exact. Assuming IEEE FP the sign bit is in the same top bit place so I'm not sure using unsigned int is advantageous here. You have to know bitwise layout of a float and byte order to do anything useful. The only machine I have ever used with an unconventional float length was a CDC 7600 (way back and 60 bits). Ideal for scientists...

Comment: If you haven't tested your code with [36-bit float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972551/17398063) it is not going to work there anyway. So a static assert is the best choice.

Comment: @MartinBrown `float` exactly encode like `double` (both as 64-bit) is allowed by C and is sometimes used in streamlined embedded processors.  FWIW, a not so old non-IEEE `float` [sample](https://www.ccsinfo.com/faq.php?page=mchp_float_format).

Answer (score 1):

Not a full-proof solution, yet a start: steer code based on the significant bit count of a `float`.
Maybe refine with other `FLT_XXX` attributes.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if FLT_MANT_DIG <= 24 + 2
  typedef uint32_t uint_flt;
#elif FLT_MANT_DIG <= 53 + 4
  typedef uint64_t uint_flt;
#else
  #error TBD code
#endif

// If we got it wrong, stop the compilation.
static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint_flt), "TBD code");
```

---

Note that a floating point type, even `float`, may be 128 bits and there is no matching integer certainly that wide.

Note that the whole `union` of a FP and integer trick is hampered that the *endian* of the two are not certainly the same.  Machines have been built this way.  So initializing with some integer constant is not a portable as one hopes.

Instead, re-write code to use an array of *bytes*.

```
union {
    float value;
    unsigned char bits[sizeof(float)];
} x;
```

---

Such code using a `union` here is often a sign of the wrong approach to achieve the higher level coding goal.
Consider stating the higher level goal.

Comment: I think we can safely assume that `float` and `uint32_t` have the same endianess if running on the same CPU+FPU.

Comment: @Lundin Safe - yes, kind of, but ... same endian-ness is not specified by C and historic counter examples exists. IMO, such mix-matched endian makes the platform a [dinosaur](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/215113/29485), yet better code would use a `static_assertion()` to test same endian-ness, than only nakedly assume the same.  Further, I still would like to know OP's higher level concern.

Comment: C doesn't specify it because it isn't C's business. And since C doesn't specify it, it is up to the application programmer to handle it in a suitable manner.

Comment: @Lundin C23/24 is venturing into endian-land, at least with integers, with `__STDC_ENDIAN_BIG__, __STDC_ENDIAN_LITTLE__, __STDC_ENDIAN_NATIVE__`.  See how that plays out once it is here.

Comment: Those are just features saving you the trouble of writing a little macro to check it - C still doesn't dictate which endianess the CPU has. `stdbit.h` does provide various oddball, supposedly portable functions though.

Comment: @chux I can recall a time pre IEEE 754 when machines radix and number of exponent bits varied almost randomly making portability of floating point data "interesting" but I can't recall any architectures where the endien-ness of FP and ints was different. I generally avoid mapping array of bytes onto floats as there is a performance hit going shorter than short int (and I can't recall any FP formats with an odd number of bytes). Some important FP algorithms rely on magic hex int constants Kahan's cbrt for instance.

Comment: @MartinBrown, The singular case I _fuzzily_ recall where FP and integers had different endian was some Motorola processor (maybe 680x0).  Perhaps its math co-processor was reversed or its soft math package was reversed or I just remember it wrong. Time to clean the cobwebs out.

Comment: @MartinBrown "I can't recall any FP formats with an odd number of bytes" --> maybe 1 32-bit "byte"?  Some TI Graphics processors?