# Do all C compilers implicitly drop the fractional when converting floating point to integer?

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, ieee-754

I notice under GCC and Clang, when I cast a `float` value to `int`, something is done on the backend to convert the true floating point data into an integer -- the fractional portion is ignored, and the whole number portion is the part which gets interpreted as `int`. For example, the expression `( unsigned int ) 101.75f` evaluates to `101`.

This is neat, but I am curious: is this just some behavior these *particular* compilers have built in, or is it actually a required feature of the C programming language?

If the former case is true, is there any way to disable this functionality? I would be interested if there is a super simple way to naively cast a `float` value to `unsigned int` without doing any "actual" conversion. For example, I used [this webpage](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to obtain the IEEE-754 representation of `101.75f`, which is `01000010110010111000000000000000`. If I were to naively interpret these 32 bits as an `unsigned int` value myself, my original expression `( unsigned int ) 101.75f` would evaluate to (depending on endianness) `1120632832` instead of `101`.

Comment: If you want do do [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) then you can't do a normal conversion. Either use a byte-wise copy with `memcpy`, or use a `union`.

Comment: float f = 101.75f; unsigned int x =* (unsigned int*)&f;

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the link; I did not know there was a word for this!

Comment: The conversion from floating types to integer types is specified in the C standard. Except when converting to `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (as you suspected), i.e. the value is truncated towards 0. If the integer part of the value cannot be represented in the integer type, the behavior is undefined. (When converting to `_Bool`, the result is 0 if the value compares equal to 0, otherwise the result is 1.)

Comment: Rather than casting to int you might be better off expressing your intention more clearly with one of trunc(), round(), ceil() or floor(). You can unpick IEEE-754 numbers but it isn't for the faint hearted and there are instructions that can do it much quicker anyway.

Comment: @Syntactics Please note that while that might work sometimes, type punning through wrong pointer type is undefined behvior. It might not work on some compilers and/or compiler settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting a floating point type to an integer type does truncate the fractional part.  This is dictated by section 6.3.1.4p1 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer
> type other than `_Bool`, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the
> value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
> cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

This is because both an explicit conversion (i.e. a cast) and an implicit conversion convert the *value* of an expression from one type to another.  What it seems like you're asking about is whether the *representation* of a `float` can be reinterpreted as an `int`.

You can use a `union` to perform such a reinterpretation:

```
union {
    unsigned int i;
    float f;
} u;
u.f =  101.75f;
printf("%u\n", u.i);
```

Comment: Deeper: `uint32_t i;` more likely to match the size of `float` than `unsigned int i;`.  Note the _endian_ of integers and FP may differ on real machines.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Wow, I never knew this. I've been casting float to int wrong my whole life thinking it was cross-platform!

Comment: @OhFiveight An `int/unsigned` is at _least_ 16-bit.  `float` is at _least_ 32[-ish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883952/2410359).

Answer (score 2):

> is this just some behavior *these particular* compilers have built in, or is it actually a required feature of the C programming language?

It is a feature of the C programming language.  The spec says:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than `_Bool`, **the
> fractional part is discarded** (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero). If the value of the integral part
> cannot be represented by the integer type, the behavior is undefined.

(C17 6.3.1.4/1; emphasis added)

You can understand this more generally as typecasts producing conversions of *values*, not of object representations.

To copy the bytes of one object's representation into a different object, use `memcpy()` or (in C, but not C++) a union.

```
float my_float = 1.234567e+08f;
uint32_t my_uint;

// with memcpy():
memcpy(&my_uint, &my_float, sizeof(my_uint));

// with a union:
union { float as_float; uint32_t as_int; } my_union = { .as_float = my_float };
uint32_t my_other_uint = my_union.as_int;
```

`memcpy()` is declared in `string.h`.

`uint32_t` is declared in `stdint.h`.

Comment: Point well taken, @chux-ReinstateMonica.  I have modified the code similarly to what you suggested.